# Printing this floating point format

Tags: c, printing, floating-point, formatting

[image: Required format]

Observe the above image, the remaining loan amount being displayed in a pretty unique way. It is basically a floating point value. When it is having no floating precision it is displayed as `$3000` when the decimal part has 4 digits 2 floating points are displayed. But when the decimal part has only 3 digits the 3 digit precision is used for floating points. Is this possible to display using only format specifiers?? I tried many combinations of `%X.Yf` but nothing worked. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using floating-point for money...

Comment: What should i use, if not float in c?

Comment: @sasidhar: Use `long long`, scaled by 100 (for cent)

Comment: @nhahtdh, maybe scaled for 1000 for 0.1 of a cent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree that using floating point for currency is not the best solution, to get the precision you want (always two digits after the point) you can use `"%.02f"`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf(".0123456789 = %.02f\n", .0123456789);
    printf("0.123456789 = %.02f\n", 0.123456789);
    printf("01.23456789 = %.02f\n", 01.23456789);
    printf("012.3456789 = %.02f\n", 012.3456789);
    printf("0123.456789 = %.02f\n", 0123.456789);
    printf("01234.56789 = %.02f\n", 01234.56789);
    printf("012345.6789 = %.02f\n", 012345.6789);
    printf("0123456.789 = %.02f\n", 0123456.789);
    printf("01234567.89 = %.02f\n", 01234567.89);
    printf("012345678.9 = %.02f\n", 012345678.9);
    printf("0123456789. = %.02f\n", 0123456789.);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from this is:

```
.0123456789 = 0.01
0.123456789 = 0.12
01.23456789 = 1.23
012.3456789 = 12.35
0123.456789 = 123.46
01234.56789 = 1234.57
012345.6789 = 12345.68
0123456.789 = 123456.79
01234567.89 = 1234567.89
012345678.9 = 12345678.90
0123456789. = 123456789.00
```

**Edit:** To have adjustable precision you can use `"%*f"`:

```
printf("123.456789 = %.*f\n", 3, 123.456789);
```

The above line will print

```
123.457
```

Comment: my problem is, the precision should automatically jump to 3 points when the decimal value decreases by 1 digit. How do you do that??

Comment: @sasidhar Edited answer to include how to do variable precision.